# Screen turns black on touching a view? what should i do to fix this?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

Everytime,I touch on a view or menu item, navigation item or anything on the screen, the screen turns black for a second(or less) and then opens another activity or Fragment. I have seen similar type of question(that is regarding scrolling a list), Does "cacheColorHint" attribute works here?

Comment: Please post code, that will be more helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: @shivam, how can i post the whole code? this thing is happening on every single touch on listview or backpress(and in many other activities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your theme:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

or , Try this in Manifest.. inside your activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
```

Comment: Thanks @batscheva . i think it is a device problem. in some device it worked but in other device it didn't.

Comment: yes ,among other things it is also depend on the device, it happens because in some complex code cases, it takes time to the possessor to load the new screen/ fragment
so if the device is better this won't happened, anyway if I helped something it is my pleasure!